# AutoMapper using built-in mappers

Tags: c#, automapper

Upgrading from AutoMapper 4.2.1 to 5.0.0 I can no longer do this without providing configuration:

```
var entity = Mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, object>, MyEntity>(feature.Attributes);
```

Previously AutoMapper would automatically work out that the Dictionary keys map directly to property names without any setup.

I've tried initializing using:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Dictionary<string, object>, MyEntity>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Dictionary<string, object>, MyOtherEntity>();
});
```

But this results in null properties in my entities as AutoMapper is no longer automatically wiring up it's previous built-in Dictionary mapper this way.

I assume I need to use something like `ProjectUsing()` but I've not managed to locate the built-in AutoMapper mappers yet.

I'm sure this is a really simple code problem to resolve. Any quick pointers? Or even link to relevant documentation that I may have somehow missed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic map:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("foo", "bar");

var test = Mapper.DynamicMap<Dictionary<string, string>>(dic);
```